# AngualrJS - KendoUI application taking long times in "Evaluate Script"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently, I am measuring and anlaysing the performance of our AngularJS-KendoUI application, and I am trying to pinpoint the bottlenecks. After following this amazing [post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/) and this great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpqZ0LjNU5A), I am analyzing the performance by Chrome DevTools timeline tab. One of the functions I cam across is "Evaluate Script" of all of my vendor js files which are kept in a single JS file :

[image: Performance Snapshot]

As you can see, the vendor.js itself is taking long time in scripting. Now let me elaborate on the contents of this file :

- AngularJS 1.2
- JQuery 1.9
- Kendo UI custom build
- Boostrap
- ES5 Shim

Now, I am confused as why evaluation of this file is taking this long. No stack trace is also provided, and it points to the first line of the file. What can be the possible reasons for this behavior?

EDIT :
Now I used the not aggregated version, i.e all vendor.js libraries are now in their respective files. Then I found kendo.custom.js taking 400+ ms in Evaluate Script :

[image: Snapshot]

Now please explain how do this behavior occurs! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The vendor.js contains all your libs, if you would know where are the bottlenecks i suggest you to use not compressed and not obfuscated js files.

This vendor file will be compressed, and all characters that's are not used by the execution engine (like end of lines or spaces) will be remove. it helps to skip space and also reduce the download time. It's why analyses stays on the first line : there is only one line in this file

I hope it may help you.

Comment: I'm not a KendoUi expert, sorry, you should create a new post which may help to understand what's happen in kendo.